# Checking if an array element(file) has a specific extension

Tags: batch-file, scripting

I'm trying to write a code that does the following. I have some files in a directory with specific extensions. I have made a vector that contains all of them. Now I will want to rename each file to something else depending on their extension. So for that I'm trying to parce the created vector with a for loop in which I check for each element extension. 
For now I won't rename it just echo it on the screen if the file with the .elf extension is found. I wrote this code but I get no echo as in there would be no .elf file in my directory. Please help me correct this. Thanks.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

cd C:\Users\uidr0938\Desktop\Copy
set path=C:\Users\uidr0938\Desktop\Copy

set /a index=0

for /r %%i in (*) do (
    set value[!index!]=%%i
    set /a index+=1
)

set /a limit=%index%-2

for /l %%a in (0;1;%limit%) do (
    if !value[%%a]! equ *.elf (
        echo !value[%%a]!
    )
)





endlocal
```

Comment: Do not set variable `PATH`, because this is system-reserved! Use a different variable name for your script!

Comment: ok will keep that in mind thank you

Answer (score 2):

try with :

```
....
for /l %%a in (0;1;%limit%) do (
    if "!value[%%a]:~-4!" equ ".elf" (
        echo !value[%%a]!
    )
)
```

when comparing string you cannot use wildcards.Here you can see some examples about batch [substrings](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html)

Comment: thank you. it worked fine. can you please explain what you did with the "~-4". I have not found much documentation online. I have an ideea but I'm not sure.

Comment: @Cantafford `:~-4` takes the last 4 symbols from a variable.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a slightly different way of doing it.

```bat
@IF NOT EXIST "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\Copy\" @EXIT/B

@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

SET "_path=%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\Copy"

SET "_index=0"
FOR /F "DELIMS=" %%A IN ('WHERE/R "%_path%" * 2^>NUL') DO (SET/A "_index+=1"
    SET "_value[!_index!]=%%A")
IF %_index% EQU 0 EXIT/B

FOR /F "TOKENS=1* DELIMS==" %%A IN ('SET _value['
) DO IF /I "%%~xB"==".elf" ECHO %%B

PAUSE
```